# SIGSEGV : QObject destruction in another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I' using Qt. I have 2 classes

Class A : takes care of a TCP connection, is a singleton for my entire program. Dispatches protocol responses to appropriate objects via QT slots (called using `QMetaMethod::invoke`, as a `QQueuedConnection`).

Class B : Is often instantiated from a QML thread, gets data from Class A (pushed).

The only way to map a protocol response to an object is via the sequence number (each request has a unique sequence number). I don't want to broadcast every response to all objects who would then filter it.

Class A keeps a map of `seq_id` : (object, method) in order to dispatch correctly. (object is a pointer to a `QObject`)

What happens is that an object of class B can be deleted any time, with responses still pending for dispatch in class A's map. This of course causes a `SIGSEGV`, and I don't know how to solve it. Listening to the `destroyed()` signal is useless, because it goes over `QQueuedConnection`. My latest idea is to make use of `deleteLater()` in the sense that object deletion would be blocked until Class A "allows" it (when it has no more open requests for that object). Any ideas about that?

Also open to other suggestions.

Comment: Is the data contained in the map `QObject`s? `QPointer` may solve your issue

Comment: Yes, they are QObjects. Sounds like it might at lease minimize the race condition. Doesn't sound like a complete fix though :
if (pointer){
   // object deleted now;
   pointer->do stuff();}
Thanks

Comment: @Armaghast I switched to `QPointer`, this allowed me to see that the issue is elsewhere. Thanks.